# Packages used in subfiles not working in main.tex

Tags: subfiles, verse, songs

I'm following Overleaf example of 'subfiles'

... and also some examples of the 'verse' and the 'song' packages

The subfiles work well but when called by main.tex the song package does not work properly

Is this common in latex, ie. that packages do not work with 'subfiles'

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfiles} 

\title{Subfiles package example}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Poems}

\subfile{sections/poems}
%\pagebreak
\section{Songs}

\subfile{sections/cords}
\end{document}
```

cords.tex

```
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\noversenumbers

\begin{document}
\songsection{Worship Songs}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
                     sr={Revelation 5:13},
                     cr={Public domain.},
                     index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

poems.tex

```
 \documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}

\poemtitle{Mathematics}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Than Tycho Brahe, or Erra Pater:}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
In mathematics he was greater \\
Than Tycho Brahe, or Erra Pater: \\
For he, by geometric scale, \\
Could take the size of pots of ale;\\
Resolve, by sines and tangents straight, \\
If bread or butter wanted weight; \\
And wisely tell what hour o’ the day \\
The clock does strike, by Algebra.
\end{verse}
\attrib{Samuel Butler (1612--1680)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When compiling `main.tex` the preambles of `cords.tex` and `poems.tex` are ignored.  You need the preamble of `main.tex` to do everything necessary for the subfiles to compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/612279/106162

Comment: I thought by using subfiles I could use packages that do not work together in a tex file. How then do people create a pamphlet with different types of typesetting?

Comment: You can get different typesetting by changing the typesetting, but if you want to use genuinely incompatible packages compiling separate documents and stitching together the PDFs with `pdfpages` is probably the easiest.

Comment: In other words, latex does not work?

Comment: LaTeX works fine, but it's as good as carrying out contradictory instructions as anything else (bad). *If* packages are incompatible (I know nothing about `songs` and `verse`, maybe they work fine together, maybe that's the question you really want to be asking here?) then there's nothing you can do unless you can patch the issue (that can sometimes be as simple as swapping the order they load, or as complicated as completely rewriting both packages).

Comment: See [Conflict between packages verse and songs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690815/110998) for how to use `verse` and `songs` in the same document.