# Conflict between packages verse and songs

Tags: verse, songs

In [a recent post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/689376/110998), @AWE reports that using the packages `verse` and `songs` in the same document leads to a clash:

> Package songs Error: Encountered \beginverse without first seeing a \beginsong line.

How can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}

\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\noversenumbers

\begin{document}
\poemtitle{Mathematics}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Than Tycho Brahe, or Erra Pater:}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
In mathematics he was greater \\
Than Tycho Brahe, or Erra Pater: \\
For he, by geometric scale, \\
Could take the size of pots of ale;\\
Resolve, by sines and tangents straight, \\
If bread or butter wanted weight; \\
And wisely tell what hour o’ the day \\
The clock does strike, by Algebra.
\end{verse}
\attrib{Samuel Butler (1612--1680)}

\songsection{Worship Songs}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
                     sr={Revelation 5:13},
                     cr={Public domain.},
                     index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX defines an environment `verse`, and both packages redefine it in incompatible ways. To fix it, proceed as follows:

1. Load the `verse` package first.

   ```
   \usepackage{verse}
   ```
2. Rename the `verse` environment to `poemverse`.

   ```
   \let\poemverse\verse
   \let\endpoemverse\endverse
   ```
3. Load the `songs` package.
4. Whenever you need the `verse` environment of the `verse` package, use `poemverse` instead.

   ```
   \begin{poemverse}
   ...
   \end{poemverse}
   ```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\let\poemverse\verse
\let\endpoemverse\endverse
\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}

\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\noversenumbers

\begin{document}
\poemtitle{Mathematics}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Than Tycho Brahe, or Erra Pater:}
\begin{poemverse}[\versewidth]
In mathematics he was greater \\
Than Tycho Brahe, or Erra Pater: \\
For he, by geometric scale, \\
Could take the size of pots of ale;\\
Resolve, by sines and tangents straight, \\
If bread or butter wanted weight; \\
And wisely tell what hour o’ the day \\
The clock does strike, by Algebra.
\end{poemverse}
\attrib{Samuel Butler (1612--1680)}

\songsection{Worship Songs}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
                     sr={Revelation 5:13},
                     cr={Public domain.},
                     index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```